# Google Search History - simple listing

Tags: google-search

I seem to remember Google's Search History being a very simple listing of all your previous searches with pagination.

Now, http://history.google.com redirects to https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity which provides quite a cumbersome interface to all your activity (e.g. there are separate blocks for each link and it uses an infinite page).

Is there a way to restore that simple history listing which had pagination and a select dropdown to choose 10, 20, 100, 500 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. They've made the activity much more "user-friendly" by breaking it up by time period.

You can get a list of only searches, though:

1. At the top of the page, click "Filter by date & product".
2. Under "Filter by Google product", uncheck "All products".
3. Scroll down and check "Search".

You can make it a more compact view by clicking the menu next to the search box (three vertical dots) and selecting "Item view" (rather than "Bundled view").

If you want an even simpler list, you'll probably need to download your search history from [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout).